# Google Directions API parse JSON output into JAVA class

Tags: json

Greetings to all Developers!

My objective is to get the latitude & longitude points along a route returned in JSON format.

In order to do so I would like to get the polyline strings at each step along the route and parse them into ArrayLists of lat & long points as described here:

http://www.geekyblogger.com/2010/12/decoding-polylines-from-google-maps.html

Before I try to re-invent the wheel...

Has anyone created a Java (Bean) Class to parse the JSON data into?

I`m hoping someone has already done so and could share this with us!

Cheers.

John.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create first java bean class/es. you can use JSONGen. then parse and map json into java bean using Gson library. e.g

```
Gson jsonParser = new Gson()
YourClass class = new YourClass;
class = jsonParser.fromJson(class)
```